# Setting the background of an EditText while keeping the line color

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, line, background-color

When the edit button is clicked on I change the EditText's appearance with:

```
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E1E2E3"));
editText.getBackground().setAlpha(80);
```

which results in this: [image]

It removes the line that appears below the text in an EditText. I've tried adding in `editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#DACC3E"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);` but that only changes the color of the background. Is there a way to get the underline back while still keeping this background color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @Bryan's answer is probably the officially recommended way to do it... There's a little workaround you can use: Just wrap the `EditText` inside a `ViewGroup` and apply your background changes to the `ViewGroup` instead of the `EditText`. e.g.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/et__parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then apply your background (might as well add the alpha to the color, too):

```
findViewById(R.id.et__parent)
    .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#50E1E2E3")); // 50 = 80 in HEX
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the background of the `EditText` to a color overrides the default background, which is the colored underline. You would have to create your own [resizable bitmap](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) to use as the background for your `EditText`.

Comment: Or cheat and wrap the EditText in a ViewGroup and apply the background color changes to the parent?

Comment: @Guardians Ah, yes, that would work too (better, even). Didn't think of that, you should post it as an answer.